# Conditionally creating variable in grouped data set based on exact time difference of two variables

Tags: r, datetime, time, conditional-statements

In the following there is an excerpt of my full data set df.

```
structure(list(Kennung = c("AO03HU23", "AO03HU23", "AO03HU23",  "AO03HU23", AO03HU23", "AO03HU23"),
minutenPrompt = c("00:09",  "00:18", "00:27", "00:36", "NA:NA", "NA:NA"),
timestamp = structure(c(1494946963,  1494947504, 1494948053, NA, NA, NA), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt" ), tzone = "UTC"),
interval.start_lastprompt = c(NA, NA, NA,  NA, NA, NA)), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")
```

Here is also a picture of it to make it more clear:

[image]

"Kennung" is something like an id which indicates all the participants under each other. Each participant has 8 rows (we can see only the first participant). Each participant was prompted (in an experiment) 4 times: They were prompted for the very first time after exactly 9 minutes (this 9 minutes are indicated by the 00:09 in "minutenprompt". Then they were further prompted for another three times (at 18, 27, and 36 minutes). Since each participant has 8 rows and "minutenPrompt" has four entries for each person (always the same entries), there are for each participant four lines "NA:NA" on "minutenPrompt".

I'm now interested in how long each participant has at least learnt in the experiment (indicated in minutes).
Since the first prompt came 9 minutes after they started learning, I need for each participant the exact time indicated in the first row of "timestamp" minus the 9 seconds indicated in the first "minutenPrompt"-field of each participant. This should give me the exact time when each person started learning. I think it would be best to also store these values in a new variable "starting.time".

And then in the next step, I need the time difference between the time they started learning and the time of each person's last timestamp (which can be in a participant's 2nd, 3rd, or 4th cell). This time interval should be printed in the `interval.start_lastprompt` variable (should indicate the minutes and seconds between the starting point and the last prompting time).

Comment: So what exactly is the desired output here for the sample input?

Comment: Is it possible that your structure command is  incorrect? Is this the exact output of the dput() command? I get an error when trying to load your dataframe.

Comment: Oh sorry, I didn't know that. The actual structure output was: `structure(list(Kennung = c("AO03HU23", "AO03HU23", "AO03HU23", 
"AO03HU23", "AO03HU23", "AO03HU23"), minutenPrompt = c("00:09", 
"00:18", "00:27", "00:36", "NA:NA", "NA:NA"), timestamp = structure(c(1494946963, 
1494947504, 1494948053, NA, NA, NA), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"
), tzone = "UTC"), interval.start_lastprompt = c(NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA)), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")`. I just changed the timestamp variable since the Citavi-Sign did appear

Comment: Better replace it in your original post...

Comment: I did repace it!

Comment: So, for the first person, I need in the first row of "interval.start_lastprompt" one value. This should be the exact minutes and seconds which lie between 2017-05-16 14:53:43 (which is 9 minutes earlier as 2017-05-16 15:02:43) and 2017-05-16 15:20:53. –

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a `tidyverse` and `lubridate` solution:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)
df %>% 
  group_by(Kennung) %>% 
  mutate(timestamp = ymd_hms(timestamp),
         interval.start_lastprompt = min(timestamp, na.rm = T) - as.difftime(9, units = 'mins'))
```

This gives us:

```
  Kennung  minutenPrompt timestamp           interval.start_lastprompt
  <chr>    <chr>         <dttm>              <dttm>                   
1 AO03HU23 00:09         2017-05-16 15:02:43 2017-05-16 14:53:43      
2 AO03HU23 00:18         2017-05-16 15:11:44 2017-05-16 14:53:43      
3 AO03HU23 00:27         2017-05-16 15:20:53 2017-05-16 14:53:43      
4 AO03HU23 00:36         NA                  2017-05-16 14:53:43      
5 AO03HU23 NA:NA         NA                  2017-05-16 14:53:43      
6 AO03HU23 NA:NA         NA                  2017-05-16 14:53:43
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I am not sure if this solution is correct. Did you subtract 9 seconds instead of 9 minutes? This is my first question and my second question is if you know how to do it as a conditional statement so that the new timestamp has only one value per participant (time of first row of timestamp MINUS 9 Minutes)?

Comment: I updated the post, I think this is what you're looking for

Comment: Thank you! This was fast and indeed is what I was looking for! I just have to figure out how to not dublicate the interval value 7 times for each person. But thanks a lot